# How to launch process into interactive session from non-interactive session in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, windows-server-2008

I have a service that runs in the non-interactive 0 session of user X, who is an admin, on Windows Server 2008.

I would like to launch processes from thisservice into an interactive (non-0) session for user X. This is so that when I decide to RDP into the server later, I can interact with the process.

The roadblock is that I cannot initially RDP into the server to create an interactive session that the service can use for launching the process into. I can do this with CreateProcessAsUser, but that requires an interactive session for user X already exists. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx.

My question is: Using .Net 4.5 (C#), is it possible to spawn/create an interactive session for user X from a service that already runs in user X's session 0? If so, how can this be done?

My main roadblock is that I cannot create this session from outside the server (through RDP or some other form of external connection).

Thank you!

Comment: Theoretically it should be possible for software running on a system to initiate an RDP connection to the same system.  Of course, this involves having an at least partly-functional RDP client.  Such clients do exist as open-source projects, but I'm not aware of any that have been ported to Windows.

Comment: The Remote Desktop Protocol Provider API should simplify this, but it is only available on Windows Server 2012 and later.

Comment: Thank you Harry! I will research if the open-source projects can be a possible solution to my use case.